# Problem sending post requests to spotify api in python

Tags: python, post, request, spotify, http-status-code-400

```
def queue_song(session_id):
    song_uri='spotify:track:5RwV8BvLfX5injfqYodke9'
    tokens = get_user_tokens(session_id)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': "Bearer " + tokens.access_token,
               }
    url = BASE_URL +'player/queue'
    data={
        'uri':song_uri
    }
    response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data).json()
    print(response)
```

Output:

```
{'error': {'status': 400, 'message': 'Required parameter uri missing'}}
```

> https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/add-to-queue

> I dont thing there is any problem with auth tokens... coz 'GET' requests are working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, using `data=` in `requests.post()` sets the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which makes the body a akin to a HTTP form request.

Spotify's API is JSON based, so your data needs to be a valid json data.

You can do it in 2 ways:

```
response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(data)).json()
```

Or, more simply:

```
response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=data).json()
```

and in this way you don't need to manually set the `application/json` header as well.

Edit:
After going through the API docs you linked, there's more wrong with the call you're making.

You're sending the parameters in `data` - which is the body of the request. But Spotify API specifies the parameters need to be put in the `Query` i.e. the query string of the URI. Which means your request should be:

```
response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,params=data).json()  # set query string not body
```

Comment: I am new to web dev and couldn't understand from the documentation that I should pass the 'song_uri' in URL. I feel your explanation really helped me understand something really important. Thank you so much for helping this newbie, not able upvote :(